# Source-tree diff summary information

Tags: linux, diff, file-diffs

I'd like to find out what has changed between versions of a large project such as Mozilla-Firefox, i.e. similar to the question but must work on Linux and is open-source.  I'm aware of [Source Code Diff / Line and File Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805090/source-code-diff-line-and-file-comparison) which is Windows based.

I currently have two large tarballs of the actual released version of Firefox 5.0 and 6.0 which I have extracted into two folders `mozilla-release-5.0/` and `mozilla-release-6.0/`

I'd like to see similar summary information for the diff of the two source trees, i.e.

• # of LINES added / removed / modified
• # of FILES added / removed / modified

Ideally these figures are for lines of source code and blank lines etc. are ignored.

Note that as this is for statistical analysis, I don't care about the actual lines themselves and I am only interested in the summary figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the histogram that for example `git diff --stat` produces for submissions, you can use "diffstat" - although it doesn't appear to be able to distinguis empty line changes.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that I have a number of release tarballs which I have extracted rather than an SCM.  Would it be simplest to load it all into `git` and do this?  I've never used `git`.

Comment: No, if you have two tarballs, you uncompress the tarballs into a directory each (e.g. dirv1 and dirv2), do `diff -r dirv1 dirv2|diffstat` and it will tell you in a nice histogram how many lines have changed in each file.

Answer (score 0):

Try also [pkgdiff](http://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/) to visualize differences between directories or packages.

Diff directories:

```
pkgdiff -d DIR-0/ DIR-1/
```

Diff packages:

```
pkgdiff PKG-0.tgz PKG-1.tgz
```

[image]

[image]